# How to open a panel with property closable true?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I posted my code below. Everything works fine while the property of the panel
(`id = "idPanemCriticas"`) `closable = "false"`.

If I change it to `true` then it does not show more messages and if I close the panel I can not open more.
I really need help, thanks.

```
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>JSF 2 + PrimeFaces</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
<p:panel id="idPanelCad" header="Cadastro de Usuário" style="width: 60%;">
<h:panelGrid columns="6">
<h:outputText value="Nome:" />
<p:inputText id="nome" value="#{loginMb.usuario.nome}" required="true" size="20"
requiredMessage="Informação do nome é obrigatório.">
<h:outputText value="*" />
</p:inputText>

<h:outputText value="Sobrnome:" />
<p:inputText id="idSobreNome" value="#{loginMb.usuario.sobreNome}"
required="true" size="20" requiredMessage="Informação do sobrenome é obrigatório.">
</p:inputText>
<h:outputText value="*" />
</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGrid columns="3">
<h:outputText value="Senha:" />
<p:password id="idSenha" value="#{loginMb.usuario.senha}" feedback="true"
required="true" requiredMessage="Informação da senha é obrigatória.">
</p:password>
<h:outputText value="*" />
</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGrid>
<p:commandButton value="Gravar" action="#{loginMb.gravar}" update="toUpdate "     
onclick="wp.show();"  process="toUpdate"/>
</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGrid>
<h:outputText value="(*) - Campos com informação obrigatórias." />
</h:panelGrid>

<p:separator> </p:separator>

<p:outputPanel id="toUpdate">
<p:panel id="idPanemCriticas" widgetVar="wp" closable="false" header="Críticas"  
rendered="true">
<p:messages id="mss" closable="true" />
</p:panel>
</p:outputPanel>

</p:panel>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `autoUpdate="true"` attribute in your `p:outputPanel`? Goal of `p:outputPanel` is to allow you [not to include an element in you element tree](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/outputPanel.jsf). In your case your embedded `p:panel` and `p:messages` are always going to be rendered, so I don't see the point of using `p:outputPanel` to achieve that.